# Css animation delay bug in chrome

Tags: css, animation, delay, fadein, loader

So, I made this really simple load-spinner with css:

```css
.loader {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  /* loader background */
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  /*loader spinner */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: fade 1s linear infinite, spin 1500ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    border-top-color: #3498db;
  }
  to {
    border-top-color: red;
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

the fact is: the spin animation starts correctly but the Fade waits something like 1 sec to start, and I really can't understand why.
Plus, this happens not in all browser: in Firefox both animations starts instantly, but in chrome this strange delay appears

Comment: I just tested this in chrome 83 and did not see any strange delay, it worked fine with the code as-is.

Comment: I'm running chrome version 83.0.4103.116 and the problem won't go away; fact is that I don't understand why the spin animation would start immediately and the fade one won't